# Fundamental Group of a Region

Tags: algebraic-topology

Compute the fundamental group of the following region at any base point. [image]

Note that we've excluded the open disk enclosed by the blue circle.

The region is certainly not convex. I tried finding an obvious deformation retract, but couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** So first I was under the impression that the region was simply connected (which as pointed out by Martin R. seems intuitively incorrect), hence the change in question. I was wondering if it would be possible to compute the fundamental group of this region ... in particular I am starting to suspect that it should have the blue circle as a deformation retract (whereupon its fundamental group should be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$), but I can't construct any deformation retraction (or prove rigorously that it is/is not simply connected).

Comment: You cannot prove it because it is not true.

Comment: Really? What is your reasoning (In particular, do you think the circle is a deformation retract)?

Comment: Because it has a hole. A circular path around that hole cannot be contracted to a point. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I suppose you are right, that is the reason why I felt that it might deformation retract onto the blue circle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This region has the property that it is radially convex (from the center of the omitted circle). So one can construct a pretty simple deformation retract. For simplicity I'll take the center of the omitted circle to be the origin and its radius to be $1$. If $R$ is the region in the picture, define the function $f\colon R\times[0,1]\to R$ by the following formula in polar coordinates:
$$
f(re^{i\theta},t) = r^te^{i\theta}.
$$
Then $f(z,1)$ is the identity function, $f(z,0)$ has image lying in the unit circle, and $f$ is continuous in both variables.

Comment: Another option, avoid polar coordinates, is just linearly scaling the norm: $f(p,t) = \left(1 + t(\frac{1}{|p|} - 1)\right)p$.